# How to use local mysql server of ubuntu in xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

Can I use mysql in xampp installed by sudo apt-get command of ubuntu  with out starting xampp's mysql server..

Comment: Use lamp for ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, of course you can.

Comment: how can i use by lampp??

Comment: A [result](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu) from a neighborhood, if you're willing to install `lamp`.

Comment: Can i use local mysql server by changing socket..??without using lampp..??

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have find the answer for my question.We can use local mysql server of ubuntu in phpmyadmin by making following changes in/opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php.

change

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'Local mysql's username';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Local mysql's password';
   /* Server parameters */
```

Change from localhost into 127.0.0.1

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
   //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

By making above changes I have access my loacl mysql server in xampp apache2 without starting xampp's mysql server

Thanks and Regards

Suriya